# explode commas but ignore commas within brackets php

Tags: php, regex, explode

I have done through with lots of answers but nothing is giving me the desired out.

I want to explode "Beer - Domestic, Food - Snacks (chips, dips, nuts), Beer - Imported, UNCATEGORIZED" and the result should be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Beer - Domestic
    [1] => Food - Snacks (chips,dips,nuts)
    [2] => Beer - Imported,
    [3] => UNCATEGORIZED
)
```

This is what I have tried

```
$string = "Beer - Domestic,Food - Snacks (chips,dips,nuts),Beer - Imported,UNCATEGORIZED";
$keywords = preg_split("/(?<=\)),/", $string);

$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $string);

preg_match_all(' /[^(,]*(?:([^)]+))?[^),]*/', $string, $matches);

preg_match_all('/[^(,\s]+|\([^)]+\)/', $string, $matches);
```

this gave me the following result

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Beer - Domestic,Food - Snacks (chips,dips,nuts)
    [1] => Beer - Imported,UNCATEGORIZED
)
```

All I want to do is explode ',' which are not inside brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make a slight correction to your current regex splitting logic by using the following pattern:

```
,(?![^(]+\))
```

This says to split on comma, but *only* if that comma does not occur inside a terms in parentheses.  It works by using a negative lookahead checking that we do not see a `)` without first seeing an opening `(`, which would imply that the comma be inside a `(...)` term.

```
$string = "Beer - Domestic,Food - Snacks (chips,dips,nuts),Beer - Imported,UNCATEGORIZED";
$keywords = preg_split("/,(?![^(]+\))/", $string);
print_r($keywords);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Beer - Domestic
    [1] => Food - Snacks (chips,dips,nuts)
    [2] => Beer - Imported
    [3] => UNCATEGORIZED
)
```